# Why is there green stuff on my heater pipe?

Tags: plumbing, heating, baseboard, copper

No, really the baseboard heat is made of copper and is constructed of a series of pipes with fins.  they look like heat sinks, or dissipation helpers.  Well, was cleaning the carpet by the baseboard heater and noticed green stuff around one of the connections between sections.  Looks like a beautiful color of green patina.  Think Statue of Liberty.

So, here's the question;  is there reason to worry?  Why is green only in one place and not along the system?  Time to call Mr. Plumber?

what do you guys think?

Comment: it's called Copper oxide, the copper equivalent of iron rust

Comment: Ever seen the [statue of liberty](https://www.google.com/search?q=statue+of+liberty&tbm=isch)?  That also happens to be copper.

Answer (score 11):

When copper oxidizes, it first turns dark brown (like a copper penny), and then if left undisturbed into a somewhat moldy-looking green. This is normal. If you notice the pipe starting to deteriorate around areas that have a lot of green, this may indicate a leak in the pipe that is introducing more water into the area, speeding oxidation.

Just keep an eye on it to ensure it isn't deteriorating. Usually, the layer of oxidation forms a good protection of the copper behind it against further oxidation, and in this way that green stuff is beneficial.